# Typescript : require statement not part of an import statement

Tags: typescript, tslint

Typescript version 2.2.2

I wrote this require in my UserRoutzr.ts

```
const users = <IUser[]> require(path.join(process.cwd() + "/data"));
```

TSLint is raising the following warning:

```
require statement not part of an import statement
```

if I changed it to :

```
import users = <IUser[]> require(path.join(process.cwd() + "/data"));
```

Then it's raising an error :

```
TS1003 Identifier expected
```

How should I rewrite this require ?
thanks for feedback

Comment: Do you need to build the path like that? cannot you just use "./data"? Assuming process is the running process.

Comment: I tried , but ./data will not be defined in the build directory... ?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

TypeScript modules are an implementation of ES6 modules. ES6 modules are static. Your issue comes from the dynamic path: `path.join(process.cwd() + "/data")`. The compiler can't determine which module it is at compile time, and the linter doesn't like the causes that lead to `any`.

You should use a static path to the module. At compile time, TypeScript resolves it. And it affects the right exported type (`IUser[]`) to `users`.

```
import users = require("./yourModuleThatExportsUsers");
```

Notice: If your module `data` contains just data, you could consider to change it to a JSON file, which could be loaded (Node.js) or bundled (Webpack).

UPDATE (from May 2019) — It is also possible to use [dynamic import](http://2ality.com/2017/01/import-operator.html), with which TypeScript accepts static and dynamic paths:

```
const users = await import("./yourModuleThatExportsUsers");
```

See also: [TypeScript 2.4 Release Notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html)

Answer (score 5):

if your can run the code correctly but eslint report an error, you can add `/* eslint-disable */`above you error code
like this

```
/* eslint-disable */
const path =  require("path");
module.exports = {
    lintOnSave: false,
    chainWebpack: config => {

        const dir = path.resolve(__dirname, "src/assets/icons");

        config.module
            .rule("svg-sprite")
            .test(/\.svg$/)
            .include.add(dir).end() // 包含 icons 目录
            .use("svg-sprite-loader").loader("svg-sprite-loader").options({extract: false}).end();
        /* eslint-disable */
        config.plugin("svg-sprite").use(require("svg-sprite-loader/plugin"), [{plainSprite: true}] || []);
        config.module.rule("svg").exclude.add(dir); // 其他 svg loader 排除 icons 目录
    }
};
```

Comment: That will disable all eslint checks for the entire file. It would be far better to disable it for only the rule and line needed.

Comment: `// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires` is a better option

Answer (score 3):

may be you need [dynamic module loading](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#dynamic-module-loading-in-nodejs), and the code like this:

```
import {IUser} from './lib/user';
const users:IUser[] = require(path.join(process.cwd() + "/data"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Needed to use provide plugin, yet neither require nor dynamic imports worked for me, this construct helped though:

```
module.exports = {
  // ..
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.plugin('provide').use(require('webpack').ProvidePlugin, [
      // ..
    ])
  },
```